# How to join 2 Webscraped lists together as one

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter

I have tried joining 2 Web-scraped lists into one list together but, all it does is show one instance. (I already have the list of names and a list of addresses made, I just want to join them).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
def get_HTML(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html
```

FIRST LIST:

```
venues_html = get_HTML('http://www.cxra.com/venues/new-york/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(venues_html, "lxml")
for venue in soup('a', attrs={'href' : '#', 'onclick' : 'return false;'}):
    display (venue.text)
```

Output:

```
'Manhattan Center Studios'
'Ellis Island'
'The TimesCenter'
'The Altman Building'
'NYIT Auditorium on Broadway'
```

SECOND LIST

```
for info in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'infoUnit col-md-6'}):
    display (info.text)
```

Output:

```
'\n \n311 West 34th Street\r\nNew York City, 94710\n\n212.613.5536\n'
'\n \nEllis Island\r\nNew York, NY 10004\n\n212.613.5535\n'
'\n \n242 W 41st St\r\nNew York, NY 10036\n\n212.613.5535\n'
'\n \n135 W 18th St\r\nNew York, NY 10011\n\n212.613.5535\n'
'\n \n1871 Broadway\r\nNew York, NY 10023\n\n212.613.5536\n'
```

Attempt of joining the two:

```
print ("Venue: " + venue.text + info.text)
```

output:

```
Venue: NYIT Auditorium on Broadway

1871 Broadway
New York, NY 10023

212.613.5536
```

I want it to do that for all of the different venues, not just one. I have tried loops, but they just seem to show that one instance repeatedly.

Comment: Please consider showing more of your code so we can take a look at the logic and see why it is showing only one instance.

Comment: @JerryHu There :)

Comment: and the display function?

Comment: @JerryHu Everything is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what display() does, my guess is that you are not printing all "instances" because you are only getting results from the very last iteration of both for loops.

Without structural change, the quickest way is to save outputs of two bs4 scraps into two lists and use a loop to display their contents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import sys

def get_HTML(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html

venues_html = get_HTML('http://www.cxra.com/venues/new-york/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(venues_html, "lxml")
print('data scrapped')

list1 = []
list2 = []

for venue in soup('a', attrs={'href' : '#', 'onclick' : 'return false;'}):
     list1.append(venue.text)

for info in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'infoUnit col-md-6'}):
    list2.append(info.text)

if len(list1) != len(list2):
    print('Two lists not aligned, aborting')
    sys.exit(0)

for index in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        print ("Venue: ", list1[index],  list2[index])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @JerryHu ! This worked! I really appreciate it mate, you've saved me so much time.